# How to create AutoCompleteTextView with suggestions from Google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create an AutoCompleteTextView, which would have the same suggestions as GoogleMaps SearchView. How can I do this? I started to read about google android apis and I am confused what API should I use.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is a `AutoCompleteTextView` with suggestions from the Google Maps API.
I recently used this tutorial on how to implement a custom `AutoCompleteTextView` with the Geocoder helper class from Google Maps API.

Here is the link: [GarbTech - Android – Implementing a Google Maps Search Box with AutoCompleteTextView and Geocoder API](http://garbtech.co.uk/android-implementing-a-google-maps-search-box-with-autocompletetextview-and-geocoder-api/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. It helps. But it outputs locations, which are not related with my current location. It probably outputs location from all over the world. Do you know how to output locations, which are near my current location?

Comment: You can try to set boundaries for the reverse search with `getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults, double lowerLeftLatitude, double lowerLeftLongitude, double upperRightLatitude, double upperRightLongitude)` method. To get the "nearby" boundaries you can use `mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds`, where `mMap` is your map instance. The return, a `LatLngBounds` will provide you the lowerLeft (southwest) and topRight (northeast) coordinates.